# Crop an image and then save it in the same directory

Tags: php, image, crop

I want to crop a part of an image of 100x100px for example from the middle to 20px height and 30px width and then save it in another file all with PHP.

I was reading and testing some code but i think im lost.

I want to do this because later i want to use OCR to get the text from the new img cropped.

Any help would be great!

Here is some code that i found in the documentation of php.net

```
<?php
// Create image instances
$src = imagecreatefrompng('waka.png');
$dest = "Select somehow /images ";

// Copy
imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 20, 13, 80, 40);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest); 

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```

Im just getting some error about the img can't show when i run it in my local server.

I'm not really sure what i need to change to get a new png. Actually i have 2 img waka.png and wuku.png for testing.

Comment: Do you any code to show us? Then we can help you to improve it in order to make something that's works. We cannot code for you.

Comment: I just add the code from php.net that i think it should be easier to me to get what i want

Comment: Did you try it? If its not your code it doesn't help us much. Try some code and tell us what the error is or what did you get that is not as expected.

Comment: This is not all the original code, in the original the source is a gif and the destination was imagecreatetruecolor(80, 40); what i want to try here is to cut a part of waka.png and save it to another new png. but when i load the code it says  "it can't show the image http://localhost/... because it have errors"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with your code, this one works for me:

```
<?php
// load your source image
$src = imagecreatefrompng('1.png');
// create an image resource of your expected size 30x20
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor(30, 20);
// Copy the image
imagecopy(
    $dest, 
    $src, 
    0,    // 0x of your destination
    0,    // 0y of your destination
    50,   // middle x of your source 
    50,   // middle y of your source
    30,  // 30px of width
    20   // 20px of height
);

// The second parameter should be the path of your destination
imagepng($dest, '2.png');

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

You should have 2.png being your cropped image.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! Thanks! i'm not really good with php.